# Easy way to steam vegetables in opened steam-in-bag kind

Tags: steaming

I bought a steam-in-bag bag of brocolli and carrots. These bags are usually microwaved without opening. E.g.: http://www.birdseye.com/vegetable-products/steamfresh-pure-simple/broccoli-florets

My 4 year old opened and ate one of the carrots. Now, I am left with an opened steam-in-bag bag which I need to steam. Of course, there are many ways of steaming vegetables but I was wondering: Is there any way of using this bag to steam the rest of the veggies?

Comment: Seal it with an all-plastic clip and cook as normal.

Comment: Add an extra tablespoon of water to the bag and cook as directed.

Comment: Insert the ingredients into a "Zip Lock" bag.

Comment: As the others pointed out, you can still use a convenient microwave steaming method, but change the container. Is there a reason why you are limiting answers to this one bag, or did you just want to say that you are not interested in answers which direct you to use something like a bamboo steamer on a hob?

Comment: @ElendilTheTall this is a good answer, as I see it. When the question is simple, the best answer can be very short and still very good.

Answer (score 1):

Put the frozen vegetables in a microwave-safe bowl and place a wet paper towel (or two) over it. Microwave for about 1-1 1/2 minutes at a time (checking that the paper towel is still moist) until the vegetables are cooked to your liking.